# could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

- I have created chain code package
- Then I have installed  `ccpack.out`
     `peer chaincode install ccpack.out`
- when I instantiate that time I got

> Error:could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1

### CLI query:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C logistic -n tradecc -l node -v 0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P 'AND('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')'
```

can any one please tell me **packaged chaincode  instantiate process**

Comment: You are giving to the script a name with the option -n, the name is tradecc. Do you have the contract tradecc and did you map the folder in which the contract is placed into the cli?

Comment: yes i have mapped .

Comment: More logs would help. For instance, the chaincode container logs if the chaincode was launched and the logs from the peer (you can even set `FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG`, `CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG` and/or `CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true` in the peer).

Comment: with out instantiate the chaincode  how can i check the chaincode logs ?? @kekomal

Comment: Sometimes the chaincode container dies just after being launched, so you can still inspect its logs. When the chaincode has not even been launched (probably your case) `CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true` in the peer improves the related logs. Anyway, the client response is not enough to discern your problem. The peer and the orderer logs are useful, too. I experienced a similar problem once caused by the peer and the chaincode containers not seeing each other through the configured IP (the host was not able to address its own public IP), but that's not probably your case.

Comment: thans   @kekomal ,@RicNtt

Answer (score 0):

finally i got solution from this doc

actually i have installed onely one peer and i have instantiate my all peers so i got 
**Error:could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1**

SOLUTON:
**########## chaincode package command #########**

```
 docker exec cli peer chaincode package -n tradecc -l node -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/`logistic`1 -v 0 -s -S ccpack.out
```

**####   installing  chaincode on peer0.org1.example.com #########**

```
docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051 -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt cli peer chaincode install ccpack.out -l node
```

**###### installing  chaincode on peer1.org1.example.com #######**

```
docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8051 -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt cli peer chaincode install ccpack.out -l node
```

**#######  installing  chaincode on peer0.org2.example.com ##########**

```
docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051 -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt cli peer chaincode install ccpack.out -l node
```

**###### installing  chaincode on peer1.org2.example.com #######**

```
docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:10051 -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt cli peer chaincode install ccpack.out -l node
```

**#### Instantiating smart contract on mychannel' #####**

```
docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C logistic -n tradecc -l node -v 0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P 'AND('\''Org1MSP.member'\'','\''Org2MSP.member'\'')' --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```

# invoke smart contract on mychannel

```
docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp cli peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C logistic -n tradecc -c '{"function":"invoke","Args":["{\"trade\":{\"Initledger\":{\"exporterName\":\"ex-raiii\",\"exportersBankName\":\"sbi\",\"exportersAccountBalance\":\"100000\",\"importerName\":\"im-ieekfvnor\",\"importersBankName\":\"kotak\",\"importersAccountBalance\":\"200000\",\"carrierName\":\"foredsty\",\"regulatorName\":\"typesgmdslcdd r-eg\"},\"flag\":\"initLedger\",\"tradeId\":\"000000100\"}}"]}' --waitForEvent --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --peerAddresses peer1.org1.example.com:8051 --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 --peerAddresses peer1.org2.example.com:10051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```

Comment: i got solution from this doc    https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/chaincode4noah.html

Comment: Of course, the chaincode must be installed in all the endorser peers belonging to organizations added to the channel in which the chaincode is going to be instantiated. Impossible to guess from the information provided, though. Many causes could have caused the chaincode container not being started and the client error message would have been exactly the same.